# How to determine if Webview in React Native Single Page Application can go back on Android?

Tags: android, react-native, android-webview

Suppose we have an Android app, then we can call `canGoBack()` to determine if the back button should go back or exit the app.

Suppose we have a RN Android app that is a multi page application, then `onNavigationStateChange()` will return if `canGoBack` is true or false.

But if it is an RN single page application, `onNavigationStateChange` is not fired on clicking a link.

There is a workaround shared [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/7602), which involves overriding history.pushState.

I was also thinking of querying the source/url/html properties of the webview but somehow they all return null. I'm not sure if this is expected or not.

Are there any better solutions to understanding if the back button should exit the app or bring the user to the previous screen?

Comment: Did you manage to find any solution? Thanks.